# How to fix 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds' in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I'm trying to work on a program with GUI, that goes through an excel file. the user is given the data written in the excel file, and if he presses accept, it should direct this data into one table. If not - the other table. I tried to work it around in any way I can find in stackoverflow but none of those seems to fix my problem. I would love for any help.

I keep getting the problem of

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/roniz/PycharmProjects/emun/manual_validation.py", line 187, in accept_query
    self.accepted.append(self.df.iloc[self.num]['bizid'])
  File "C:\Users\roniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1424, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\roniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2157, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\roniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2088, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

And if not that one, I get the same just written differently.

I tried to transfer data as a one row dictionary, I tried to transfer the data in different locations of the code.

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
import googlemaps
import pandas as pd
import requests


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.parent = master
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(self)

        self.df = pd.read_excel('checkformanual.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1", header=0)
        self.num = 0
        self.gpi = self.df.iloc[self.num]['googleid']  # @todo: lo#

        self.accepted = []
        self.declined = []

        self.butt1 = Tkinter.Button(frame, text='Accept', command=self.accept_query)
        self.butt2 = Tkinter.Button(frame, text='Decline', command=self.decline_query)

        frame.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, side=Tkinter.BOTTOM)
        self.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

    def accept_query(self):
        self.num += 1
        self.accepted.append(self.df.iloc[self.num]['bizid'])

    def decline_query(self):
        self.num += 1
        self.declined.append(self.df.iloc[self.num]['bizid'])

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()

    accepteddf = app.df[app.df['bizid'].isin(app.accepted)]
    declineddf = app.df[app.df['bizid'].isin(app.declined)]

    accepteddf.to_excel("accepted.xlsx", index=False)
    declineddf.to_excel("declined.xlsx", index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon you're right, sorry about that. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this function:

```
def accept_query(self):
        self.num += 1
        self.accepted.append(self.df.iloc[self.num]['bizid'])
```

Specifically, with `iloc[self.num]`. This operation will raise an `IndexError` exception if the supplied integer-index (in this case `self.num`) is out-of-bounds. The fact that you're incrementing `self.num` before appending to `self.accepted` seems suspicious, but maybe that's deliberate. In any case, it's difficult to diagnose the problem further without seeing at least a screenshot of the excel file.